# highcharts cambiar fuente a leyenda

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo unas graficas de tipo columna o barras, mi pregunta es sobre los titulos de el eje x, en categories.
Hay forma de cambiar el estilo, sobre titulo en especifico?, ya que he podido cambiar el estilo solo que se aplica a todas los titulos.
Les agradeceria su respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes definir algo parecido a esto en tu grafico

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug'],
    labels:{
     style: {
      color: 'red',
        fontSize:'20px';
    }
  }
}
```

Debes definir en tu xAxis como se muestra en el ejemplo te añado un enlace donde puedes ver que tipos de estilos soporta y un ejemplo

[Ejemplo en linea](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-style/)

[Otro ejemplo que te puede servir](http://jsfiddle.net/508jej83/)

[Que estilos soporta](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.style)

[Tipos de estilos que puedes declarar en los graficos](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.CSSObject)

espero te sirva

Comment: He modificado mi pregunta, la habia explicado mal, me refiero a los titulos del eje X, que aparece debajo de cada columna, aplicarle un estilo a una posicion en especifico

Comment: Modifique la respuesta espero te sirva